# Add first parameter in the query string

Tags: javascript

I have a url like "http://localhost:8080/myapp?age=12&add=mumbai&name=myname"
Now I want to add one parameter(tel=12345) as the first parameter in the query string like
"http://localhost:8080/myapp?tel=12345&age=12&add=mumbai&name=myname"

I have tried below snippet

```
var str = "http://localhost:8080/myapp?age=12&add=mumbai&name=myname";

var txt2 = str.slice(0, str.indexOf("?")) + "tel=12345&" + str.slice(str.indexOf("?"));
alert(txt2);
```

But the result is incorrect

http://localhost:8080/myapptel=12345&?age=12&add=mumbai&name=myname

Is there a better way???

Comment: why can't you use simple string concatenation? any particular reason behind this?

Comment: I have a requirement where I want to add it as a first parameter and not append it in the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to just increment index by 1 and this will work.

E.g.:

```
var txt2 = str.slice(0, str.indexOf("?") + 1 ) + "tel=12345&" + str.slice(str.indexOf("?") + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var str = "http://localhost:8080/myapp?age=12&add=mumbai&name=myname";

var txt2 = str.slice(0, str.indexOf("?")) + "?" + "tel=12345&"
//                                        ^^^^^
    + str.slice(str.indexOf("?") + 1);
//                               ^^^

alert(txt2);
```

Comment: It gives "localhost:8080/myapp?tel=12345&?age=12&add=mumbai&name=myname"

Comment: Yes, sorry. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
var txt2=str.split('?')[0]+'?tel=12345&'+str.split('?')[1];
```

Just a variation.